# Using AJAX/Jquery to Replace div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, yii

I am trying to set the content of an empty div after an AJAX call with the `data` message. I also wired the function to my `CHtml::submitButton`, which should call the function when clicked, but nothing is happening. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="myResult">        
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
function successMessage(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: "<div> Replace div with this contentf</div>",
        success: function(data){
            $('myResult').html(data);
        }
    })
}
```

**PHP:**

```
echo CHtml::beginForm(array('myForm'), 'get', array('form'));
echo '<div class="row form">';
echo '<div class="row buttons">';
echo CHtml::submitButton('Download Content', array('htmlOptions' => 'successMessage()'));
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Assuming: `$('#myResult').html(data);` Is it possible your data is placed, then the form submit completes and refreshes the page ... wiping myResult?

Comment: @rfornal what's the best way to fix this?

Comment: Typically, what I've seen is there is no formal submit button tied to the <form>, then this type of a change and the actual submission of the form are $.ajax ...

Comment: However, I suppose you could send the data results as a part of the $SESSION variables so that you can use them after the refresh.

Comment: Could you expand? I don't fully understand.

Comment: Part 1: With a standard button (no submit), you can use jQuery to capture the click event and post the changes to the API via $.ajax.  This way, the page does not reload as it would with a submit button.  Then, the changes as you've tried above would be visible a lot longer.

Comment: Part 2: Since you are using PHP, another option would be to store the result information in the $_SESSION variable which does not get eliminated when a page reloads (such as on a submit), then if you check $_SESSION and see data, you can immediately display it on the refreshed page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
             url: "test.html",
            type: "GET",
            data: "<div> Replace div with this contentf</div>",
            success: function(data){
                $('#myResult').html(data);
            }
        })
```

selector jQuery incorrect in response ajax. and define Url in ajax.

Comment: check console send ajax request?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem relies in the following line:

```
$('myResult').html(data);
```

Here, you are trying to do a jquery selection to an  element, which you are not using in your html (this is only possible via pollyfils). So you have to select the element by its ID:

```
$('#myResult').html(data);
```

And another thing i've seen, what is the url where you are doing the request?

```
<script>
    function successMessage(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/please/add/an/url/",
            data: "<div> Replace div with this contentf</div>",
            success: function(data){
                $('myResult').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check my edit regarding the url in your ajax request.

Comment: Hey @taxicala, I added the URL to my project, but it still doesn't run. Could it be that my page is refreshing after clicking my button? If so, not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, when you are using onclick function like this :

```
<input type="submit" onclick="successMessage()">
```

you should use this instead:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="successMessage();result false;">
```

but when you are already using jquery, then better approach is:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
        successMessage(){
           // your ajax goes here
        }

        $('#myResult').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          successMessage();
        });
     });
```

Then you need to repair your successMessage function. You see, the data you are setting there are not the data, that are coming out as an output. If you need ajax then you probably want to get the result from some php script on some other url. Then you should do it like this :

```
function successMessage(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url : 'index2.php',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { mydata: '<div> Replace div with this content</div>'},
            success: function(data){             
                $('#myResult').html(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

Then you need a php file named index2.php which can look like this :

```
<?php
    echo json_encode($_GET['variable']);
?>
```

And i dont know if this your line :

```
echo CHtml::submitButton('Download Content', array('htmlOptions' => 'successMessage()'));
```

also put the `</form>` tag after the form to close it.

This should work for you. I tried it and it works fine.

Comment: I need to use the `echo CHtml::submitButton('Download Content', array('htmlOptions' => 'successMessage()'));` will your code not work with this!?

Comment: Try echo CHtml::submitButton('Download Content', array('htmlOptions' => 'successMessage();return false;')); It should get the same result as <input type="submit" onclick="successMessage();result false;">

Comment: Yeah, I implemented your code and can't get it to work. Really strange.

Comment: When you try to inspect element on the submit button does it looks like this? <input type="submit" onclick="successMessage();result false;"> Also try to use console.log(data) to see if it gives you some result. And did you create that index2.php file and put it into the same directory?

Comment: @YoungandFree any updates? Did you figure out your problem or is it still persisting? Let us know so we can help you. If the question was already answered then check the answer as right.